# How to find shape and scale parameters for a Weibull distribution in survival analysis

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, survival, clinical-trials, weibull-distribution

I am to run a superiority clinical trial and I want to fit a parametric model under the Weibull Distribution.

But I am confused about how should I find the **shape** and **scale** parameters for the **Weibull** **distribution** ?

Is there any formula or R code for it ?

Any kind of guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: The answer is simple if you're just looking for code. However, it's also offtopic. Anyway in the survival package, look up ?survreg.

Comment: To my recollection there's some discussion of the connection between the shape and scale parameters and the parameterization in the output of parametric Weibull survival model (R's `survreg`) in at least a few posts on site (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/419506/805), turned up in my first attempt at a search for it), but as Adam points out, the model is also discussed in the help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @AdamO

Comment: Thank you so much @Glen_b

Comment: Be very careful, as different parameterizations of the Weibull distribution lead to different interpretations of "shape" or "scale"; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/466721/28500) for example.

Comment: Thank you.. @EdM